# Python: plot shown differently in pyplot than in tkinter?

Tags: python, plot, tkinter

I wanted to add some comments outside the plots. The code and figures are d below. The problem is that fig2 essentially the same but with the "text1" and "text2" cut off. Can anybody explain why or provide a better solution of adding texts outside the plot? Thanks a lot!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

import Tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()

x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
textx = ax.get_xlim()[0]
texty = ax.get_ylim()[0]
ydist = ax.get_yticks()[1] - ax.get_yticks()[0]
ax.text(textx, texty-2*ydist, "text1")
ax.text(textx, texty-3*ydist, "text2")
fig1.show()
```

[image]

```
fig2 = plt.Figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(x,y)
textx = ax2.get_xlim()[0]
texty = ax2.get_ylim()[0]
ydist = ax2.get_yticks()[1] - ax2.get_yticks()[0]
ax2.text(textx, texty-2*ydist, "text1")
ax2.text(textx, texty-3*ydist, "text2")
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1.0)
canvas.show()
canvas.draw()
Tk.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: what happens if you do `fig2.tight_layout()` before you show it?

Comment: Paul, thanks a lot for editing the question and comment! I just tried, and found it the same as without the "fig2.tight_layout()".

Comment: Can you drag the bottom of the window down to reveal the text elements?

Comment: Also, what happens when you save both figures as image files? Eg, `fig1.savefig("fig1.png")`

Comment: Paul, thanks for your suggestion! Very interesting, both fig1 and fig2 saved WITHOUT the texts below the chart.

Comment: Dragging the window didn't reveal the text, as expected.